# Filter duplicate rows while importing data using pandas to_sql

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I am using pandas to import data into a postgres database from an xlsx file and I want to filter duplicate values while importing the file.
I am using this method to skip duplicate rows based on the primary key column:

```py
    def insert_on_duplicate(table, conn, keys, data_iter):
        insert_stmt = insert(table.table).values(list(data_iter))
        on_duplicate_key_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_nothing(index_elements=[id_column])
        conn.execute(on_duplicate_key_stmt)
    df.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='append', chunksize=4096, method=insert_on_duplicate, index=False)
```

I'm going to be honest, I haven't found any explanation on how to skip dupe data while import, only using this 'method' which I did not understand. I know it works, I tried it with a test dataset, but after trying to use it on the real file, it started to throw this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidColumnReference) there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
```

At first I thought that maybe this means that there aren't any rows that are both in the file and the database, and it gets an error because it didn't find anything. But after checking I realized that it is not the case, there are rows which are in both the file and the database. I have looked through my code several times and I can't find why it works one time and next time it doesn't.

Comment: According to the error message, the conflict has to arise due to violation of a PK/Unique constraint.  Is there such a constraint on `id_column` in your table?

Comment: Yes, there is. But that's the point, I don't want to allow non-unique rows to be added.